# Is it possible to remove the password field on the WAAD sign-in page when SSO is in use?

Tags: azure, adfs2.0, azure-active-directory

We have a Windows Azure Active Directory, configured with a custom domain, linked to an on-premise ADFS (2.0) server for federated authentication.

When I go to https://manage.windowsazure.net in a clean browser session, I'm prompted by https://login.microsoft.online.com for just an email address. This asks for Organizational vs. Microsoft account, and if I select Organizational, I'm redirected to our ADFS server - all good.

On the other hand, on our own ASP.NET MVC applications which use ADAL, the login page (again login.microsoftonline.com) shows both a username and password box. If you type a username, then focus on to the password box, you then get redirect at that point to ADFS.

This can be a rather confusing user experience - often you've started typing your password by the time the redirect happens, then hit enter, and of course get an authentication failure.

Possibly a better demonstration in this screen recording: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZYPltSmcn8&feature=youtu.be

Is there any way of using the username-only page rather than username + password, or better yet, skipping the WAAD page and redirecting straight to ADFS? (Since all users will be using that for SSO anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

The Azure portal has the email-only screen mostly because it needs to disambiguate between Azure AD accounts (organizational accounts) and Microsoft accounts (personal accounts, formerly LiveIDs).

If you provide the email address as the `login_hint` parameter in the OAuth 2.0 authorization request, Azure AD will do the lookup to find out if it's a federated domain, and if so, immediately redirect to ADFS.

With ADAL, you can provide this using [`AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken(String, String, Uri, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn479468.aspx) to specify `loginHint`:

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = 
    authContext.AquireToken(resource, clientId, returnUri, loginHint);
```

You will, however, have to build your own page to collect the email address.